# How to stop mysql from exiting query on error?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm loading a lot of data from long files into my database with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, however whenever there's a line that either doesn't conform to the column amount, uses incorrect string values, or is too long for the column, the entire query simply exits.

Is there a way to force the query to just skip the erroring line whenever there's an error? I tried the `--force` argument, but that doesn't seem to do anything to solve it.

My query:

```sql
LOAD DATA CONCURRENT INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':DELIMITER:' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2) SET column_1=@col1,column_2=@col2
```

I don't mind dropping the lines with errors in them since they're not useful data anyway, but I do care about all the data after the erroring line.

Comment: Try using the `IGNORE` modifier: `LOAD DATA CONCURRENT INFILE 'file_name' IGNORE INFO TABLE ...`

Comment: Read the documentation about this, as it's affected by the SQL_MODE setting. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html and look for "restrictive"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `IGNORE` to your command will skip the erroneous lines

Example:

```
LOAD DATA CONCURRENT INFILE 'file_name' IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':DELIMITER:' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1,@col2) SET column_2=@col1,column_2=@col2
```